# Is it possible to update apiVersion in Chart.yaml dynamically depending on helm client while installing the helm chart?

Tags: kubernetes-helm

Sample Chart.yaml:

```
apiVersion: v1
description: xyz
name: xyz
...
```

So if we are installing the chart using helm client v3.x, then `apiVersion` should be set to `v2`.
Otherwise, set `apiVersion` to `v1`.

Comment: The two file formats are different, and I think Helm 3 supports `v1` `Chart.yaml` files as-is.  What's the larger problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: Though helm 3 supports `v1` also. But as `apiVersion: v2` in helm v3 provides better security thats why our requirement is use `apiVersion: v2` when using helm v3 else `apiVersion: v1` though rest helm chart content will be same.